# How to generate locale properties file from my Messages interface?

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I am implementing an internationalized GWT application at the moment. I read the related documentation and have created the necessary interface that extends `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages`. I'd like to use MD5 key generation. The methods are annotated like this:

```
@DefaultMessage("Demo")
@Description("A menu item's label")
@Meaning("Nothing special so far")
String bucketDemo();
```

How could I automatically generate the translatable .properties files based on the interface? I see that i18nCreator is for generating the interface and the properties file the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG, I missed the point that this file is automatically generated by the GWT Compiler.. :-)